# Lego Mindstorms NXT, NXC: Error in replacing elements in an array (no matter the dimension)

Tags: c, arrays, lego-mindstorms, nxc

I tried to write a simple fifteen puzzle for the **Lego Mindstorms NXT** block using **Bricx Command Center**. But there's always the same problem. The elements of the array (no matter the dimension) won't change the second time.

Here's the code that simulates the error. In case you don't have an NXC block to check it out, the program outputs a 4x4 grid of zeroes (and it's ok) and then the program exits with "File error!" on the LCD screen, presumably while trying to change the first zero element of the array with 1.

If you have any thoughts please let me know. I presume that NXC language wasn't developed to work with arrays in that particular way though I find it odd and strange..

P.S. I also tried to use the built in function ArrayReplace() though with no success.

Here's the code example:

```
int count;
int numMatrix[] = {1, 2 ,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 69};
const int xcoord[] = {12, 37, 62, 87};
const int ycoord[] = {56, 40, 24, 8};

void fillGrid(){
     int j, k;
     for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
         numMatrix[i] = count;
         if (k == 4){
            k = 0;
            j++;
         }
         NumOut(xcoord[j], ycoord[k], numMatrix[i]);
         Wait(50);
         k++;
         }
     Wait(2000);
     ClearScreen();
}

task main(){
     while (true){
           fillGrid();
           count++;
     }
}
```

Okay, that was clearly my bad, I should have initialized the j and k local variables and equal them to 0. Now take a look at this situation where I try to do the same with 2 dimensional array.

```
#define NROWS    4
#define NCOLUMNS 4

int count;
int numMatrix[NROWS][NCOLUMNS] = {
    { 1,  2,  3,  4},
    { 5,  6,  7,  8},
    { 9, 10, 11, 12},
    {13, 14, 15, 69} };
const int xcoord[] = {12, 37, 62, 87};
const int ycoord[] = {56, 40, 24, 8};

void fillGrid(){
     for (int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < NCOLUMNS; j++){
             numMatrix[j][i] = count;
             NumOut(xcoord[i], ycoord[j], numMatrix[j][i]);
             Wait(50);
         }
     }
     Wait(2000);
     ClearScreen();
}

task main(){
     while (true){
           fillGrid();
           count++;
     }
}
```

Nothing will change all of the elements of the array will remain the same as they were initialized (1, 2, 3...). Now it's getting more interesting..

Comment: What are the values of `j` and `k` the very first time through the loop?

Comment: As they are initialized, they are both 0.

Comment: If those were file-scope like `count` is, they would be zero, but `i` and `j` are local so have whatever random values are found on the stack. Initialize them explicitly.

Comment: You are totally correct! My mistake.

Comment: The posted code will cause a matrix of 15 0s then a matrix of 15 1s, ... then a matrix of 15 15s,  Then a matrix of 15 16s .... until 15 max ints then the next value displayed is undefined.   Suggest the line in `main()`:  `count++;`  be followed by the line: `count = count %16;`

Comment: I'm not sure I can tell what this code is trying to accomplish...?

Comment: Maybe it's not the best representation, I'm trying to do the same but this time with 2d array. I want all of the elements to be replaced with 0 then 1, 2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: in C, **local** variables are allocated on the stack and are *not* initialized for you by default, you have to do this yourself.

```
int count;               // global: automatically initialized to zero

void fillGrid() {
     int j = 0, k = 0;   // local: NOT automatically initialize - you do it.

     for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
         numMatrix[i] = count;
         if (k == 4){
            k = 0;
            j++;
         }
         NumOut(xcoord[j], ycoord[k], numMatrix[i]);
         Wait(50);
         k++;
     }
    ...
}
```

If you have not initialized them, you get random trash whatever happens to be on the stack: on my system, `j` does happen to be zero, but `k` is 4195392.

> I presume that NXC language wasn't developed to work with arrays in that particular way

This actually doesn't have anything to do with it: the library code (say, `NumOut`) never sees the arrays, only the individual values that are indexed from the array and passed separately to the library.

Comment: I've edited the question, you can now have a look at the problem described.